# Zeebus Puzzle #6

Tags: word, rebus, knowledge

Walkers beware! You may not want to take a shot at this one...

[image]

Comment: I just keep thinking Kevin Bacon and Francis Bacon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this

> Kevin Spacey is Francis Underwood?

The reference is to

> House of Cards, where Kevin Spacey played the character of Francis Underwood.

The following line contains spoilers for both this puzzle and the underlying reference.

> "Walkers Beware" is a reference to Garrett Walker, the president of the US before Underwood, whose resignation was brought about by Underwood.

Comment: El-Guest, thanks for elaborating on the clue. I was hoping somebody would catch that ;) +1

Comment: Haha no worries, @zeethreepio! Great puzzle! :D